# Combining two similar entries in a row and output their sum

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch entries in a table that are the same and combine their values into one on display. I am using laravel framework.
This what did so far

```
public function material_approve($id)
{$totalcost = DB::table('tbl_material_requests')
->where('m1number', $id)
->sum(DB::raw('tbl_material_requests.material_quantity * tbl_material_requests.material_cost'));
$material = DB::table('tbl_material_requests')
->where('m1number', $id)
->get();
$m1_no = $id;}
```

Here is the table migration

```
Schema::create('tbl_material_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('m1number');
$table->string('material_unit');
$table->integer('material_status');
$table->integer('material_quantity');
$table->integer('material_cost');
$table->string('material_name');
$table->timestamps();});
```

Here is the screen shot of the result

[image: this is the result showing two entries of tap i want to diplay it as one entry and find its total]

Thank you in advance

Comment: What defines "in a row"?  Database tables are _not_ ordered.

Comment: i did not get your question well sir

Comment: What defines "similar entries"?

Comment: like the shwo screenshot tap is repeated twice..it should have only one instance of tap and show the totals like "Tap 13 pieces 599" in a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `GROUP BY` is the technique you are looking for:

```
SELECT material,
       SUM(quantity) as TotQuantity,
       SUM(material_cost) as TotCost
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY material;
```

(No, I can't translate that into Lavavel; it adds complexity that I don't need.)

Comment: let me try then get back to you